# Deploy error on MAVEN run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am currently getting this error while trying to execute the deploy

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] Total time: 14.761 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-06T16:48:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/259M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven plugin:1.0.0.Beta1:deploy (default) on project spm5: Could not execute goal deploy on D:\DIVERSE\Utile\Programe\Eclipse Neon\workspace\SPM5Rest\target\SPM5.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{

[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
`
```

> I don't know why do I get the  JBAS012144 error on localhost:9990 since I'm using the administration console in port 9992. Or what is the cause for this?

Comment: do you need to add a proxy to your settings.xml

Comment: `http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out` look strange?

Comment: @khmarbaise If I type localhost:9990 it doesn't display anything. I changed the port in standalone.xml to 9992 and I can access the administration console from wildfy. But if I try to deploy in eclipse, it shows that error

Comment: Can you show the pom of your project please.

Comment: I solved this problem. A service called Nvidia Network Service was using the same 9990 port. :/